# aggregate on many to many in django orm

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

i want to create a report for sum of duration that a adviser advise on this month.
my model :

```
class Adviser(models.AbstractBaseModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField('accounts.User', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='adviser')
    patients = models.ManyToManyField('patient.Patient', through='adviser.AdviserPatient', related_name='advisers')

class AdviserPatient(models.AbstractBaseModel):
    adviser = models.ForeignKey('adviser.Adviser', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='adviser_patient')
    patient = models.ForeignKey('patient.Patient', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='adviser_patient')
    duration = models.SmallIntegerField()
    assign_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    release_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

class Patient(models.AbstractBaseModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField('accounts.User', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='patient')
```

my query :

```
ended_advise_this_mouth = Adviser.objects.annotate(
                total=Case(When(
                    adviser_patient__release_date__gte=start_of_month(),
                    adviser_patient__release_date__lte=end_of_month(),
                    then=Sum('adviser_patient__duration')), default=Value(0), output_field=IntegerField()))
```

but with this query i get duplicated adviser like that :

```
<QuerySet [<Adviser: [1 None None]>, <Adviser: [1 None None]>, <Adviser: [1 None None]>, <Adviser: [1 None None]>, <Adviser: [1 None None]>, <Adviser: [1 None None]>, <Adviser: [2 vahid imanian]>]>
```

as you see adviser 1 repeat 6 time with separate total .
when i use method values('id') or use distinct() not effected in result . my db is mysql and cant use distinct('id').
i need a querysetfor pass serializer please help me to fix this query and
is there any way to use django-rest-framework serializers for this queryset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a `Case` `When`, for each `adviser_patient` line it will check if it is in range, and use the `Sum` of that single line (hence the duration itself), or `0` in case it is out of range.

You thus need to aggregate a level higher:

```
from django.db.models import IntegerField, Q, Sum, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

# since Django-2.0
ended_advise_this_mouth = Adviser.objects.annotate(
    total=Coalesce(Sum(
        'adviser_patient__duration',
        filter=Q(
            adviser_patient__release_date__gte=start_of_month(),
            adviser_patient__release_date__lte=end_of_month()
        ),
        output_field=IntegerField()
    ), Value(0))
)
```

Comment: thanks for answer , how can i compute duration of advise that in this month . its means that may start in past month (duration of this month must be compute) and its start and end in this month and start this month and end next month( duration of this month must be compute) thanks again for your answer